# IOS CollectionView "A Worked Example"

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to get code working to create a collectionView to create a Hierarchical view of my core data just like Apple's example, however I do not understand how they are explaining how to use the supplementary view to represent the lines connecting the cells.

For example, do I create 1 supplemental view and use subviews to create the connection lines positioned between the data objects or...

Do I create many supplemental views each containing the connection line graphics and position them between the data objects?

Many Thanks

Apple's documentation see link..

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/AWorkedExample/AWorkedExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH8-SW6

Listing 6-9  Creating attributes objects for supplementary views

```
// create another dictionary to specifically house the attributes for the supplementary view
NSMutableDictionary *supplementaryInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
//…
// within the initial pass over the data, create a set of attributes for the supplementary views as well
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *supplementaryAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:@"ConnectionViewKind" withIndexPath:indexPath];
[supplementaryInfo setObject: supplementaryAttributes forKey:indexPath];
//…
// in the second pass over the data, set the frame for the supplementary views just as you did for the cells
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *supplementaryAttributes = [supplementaryInfo objectForKey:indexPath];
supplementaryAttributes.frame = [self frameForSupplementaryViewOfKind:@"ConnectionViewKind" AtIndexPath:indexPath];
[supplementaryInfo setObject:supplementaryAttributes ForKey:indexPath];
//...
// before setting the instance version of _layoutInformation, insert the local supplementaryInfo dictionary into the local layoutInformation dictionary
[layoutInformation setObject:supplementaryInfo forKey:@"ConnectionViewKind"];
```